# Spark Dataframe delete to Elasticsearch

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark, elasticsearch, apache-spark-sql

I am using Apache Spark DataFrame and I want to Delete data to Elasticsearch.
For adding and updating I am using below command

```scala
val esURL = "https://56h874526b6741db87c3c91324g755.westeurope.azure.elastic-cloud.com:9243"
 var indexName =  "test_elastic/test_elastic"
    df.write
      .format("org.elasticsearch.spark.sql")
      .option("es.nodes.wan.only","true")
      .option("es.port","443")
      .option("es.net.ssl","true")
      .option("es.net.http.auth.user","userid")
      .option("es.net.http.auth.pass","pwd")
      .option("es.nodes", esURL)
      .option("es.mapping.id", "primary_key")
      .mode("append")
      .save(indexName)
```

My question is how I can delete some rows from elasticsearch index. In my case elasticsearch index is "test_elastic".

Comment: you don't need spark to delete records.. https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-delete.html

Comment: @undefined_variable, You want to say that I can delete one by one only. It is not possible to pass whole dataframe to delete entire required document id.

Comment: there is bulk delete option.. but spark is not the correct tool to achieve what you are looking for.. as mentioned in the answer dataframe "overwrite" will be much more costly compared to bulk delete

Comment: We are using azure databrick notebook to accomplish this task and on the same notebook we are performing many task include this delete operation so can't use other tool. language we are using scala. I tried with curl and it is deleting only one record so I will check bulk delete if it is possible from databrick notebook.

Answer (score 0):

A quick search in the repository mentions first support for deletes on the ElasticSearch Hadoop connector for the 8.x and 7.8 versions, neither of which are currently released the moment I write this.

https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-hadoop/pull/1324

From maintainer jbaiera :

> jbaiera left a comment •
>
> LGTM! Thanks very much for your dedication on getting this in! I'll go ahead and merge it in to master and backport it to the 7.x branch. It should be available in the 7.8.0 release when that lands.

From the current code changes, supported ES versions should be 2.x to 8.x, but there is no documentation yet that I could find (did not look much though), and no information about a direct usage in the Spark API (and I'm not even sure a delete API exists on Spark Dataframes, whatever their data source).

On the other hand, there exists a write mode called "overwrite", that is working and could allow you achieve data deletion, but overwriting the whole index may not be practical depending on the volumetry.

I *think* your best bet would be to drop out of the spark dataframe API to switch to one (or several) direct call(s) to [bulk delete](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-bulk.html).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. We are restrict to use the spark dataframe API so I will try your answer in same spark dataframe and lets see if it will works.

Comment: You are restricted to use an API that does not exist ? (As I said, there is no delete operation on the Spark Dataframe API...) Does not exactly look like the restriction is made by sensible people... Well, you could always (pseudo code) `dataframe.forEachPartition(part => { esClient = x; delete = esClient.prepareBulk(); part.forEach(element => delete.add(element)) ; delte.execute(); esClient.close(); ) }`.

Comment: Thanks @GPI, I got your point that there are no direct API for delete operation from spark dataframe. I tried below curl operation from databrick notebook (scala ) and it is deleting one record.  `%sh curl -u user:pwd  https://56h874526b6741db87c3c91324g755.westeurope.azure.elastic-cloud.com:9243/test_elastic/_search?q=name:Robert,,Williams`

Comment: the example that you mentioned is any source for that for deletion.